# Mutiny.SessionFactory: use existing session for saving entities

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, sessionfactory, mutiny

I have simple task: get data by artemis connection -> save data to DB. If we have open session - use it. Function for saving:

```
fun <T> merge(entity: T): Uni<T> {
        return sessionFactory.withTransaction { session -> session.merge(entity) }
}
```

If we have a single or rare event, then it works. But if we have several events in a short period of time (example two), then not all data is saved. Data from first event was saved, from second wasn't.
Using logging and tests I reproduced this behavior:

```
sessionFactory.withTransaction { session1 ->
    session1.merge(entity1).invoke { _ ->
        sessionFactory.withTransaction { session2 ->
            session2.merge(entity2)
        }.subscribe().with(
            { println("success save entity2: $entity2") },
            { error -> println("error save entity2: $error") }
        )
    }
}.subscribe().with(
    { println("success save entity1: $entity1") },
    { error -> println("error save entity1: $error") }
)
```

That is, if data recording from the second event started after the ***merge*** function was called, but before the session was closed, the data will not be saved.

Next1. If I use an ***persist*** instead of a ***merge*** (`session2.merge -> session2.persist`), the data will be saved.

Next2. If I add a ***find*** before ***persist*** - behavior is the same as ***merge*** (doesn't save):

```
sessionFactory.withTransaction { session2 ->
    session2.find(Entry::class.java, entity2.id)
        .flatMap { session2.persist(entity2) }
//    session2.merge(entity2)
}
```

Next3. If I add ***flush*** before ***merge*** - I get error:

```
sessionFactory.withTransaction { session2 ->
    session2.flush()
        .flatMap { session2.merge(entity2) }
//    session2.merge(entity2)
}
```

```
E 13:24:23 23 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] errors.logSqlException - HR000057: Failed to execute statement [$1/* load Entity */ select entity0_.id as id1_3_0_, ... from Entity entity0_ where entity0_.id=$1]: $2could not load an entity: [Entity#b3c699b4-d490-4e56-bb76-904a1cb508a1]
error save entity2: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (25P02)
error save entity1: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entity_pkey" (23505)
```

Where *b3c699b4-d490-4e56-bb76-904a1cb508a1* is ***entity2.id***.

In this case, the ***entity1*** is saved twice: first time after ***session2.flush()*** and second before session1 closing.

**Question: how do save data from both events using an existing session?** If I open a new session every time, there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the initial example, you are using `.invoke` instead of `.call` and there's no need to subscribe twice. But you also need to make sure the same session is not shared in parallel between pipelines.

What I mean is you shouldn't rely on code like this:

```java
List<Uni<Void>> list = ...
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    list.add( session.persist(entity) );
}
Uni.join().all( list ).chain(session::flush);
```

It might look like it works in some cases, but it can lead to errors that are hard to debug. [That's because the session is not thread-safe](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_sessions_and_vert_x_contexts).

In your case, if you want to merge two entities using the same session, you need to make sure that the operations happen in the right order.

This should work for example:

```kotlin
sessionFactory.withTransaction { session ->
    session.merge(entity1)
        .invoke{ entity -> println("success save entity1: $entity") }
        .call { _ ->
            session.merge(entity2)
                    .invoke{ entity -> println("success save entity2: $entity") }
         }
}.subscribe().with(
    { println("Finished!") },
    { error -> println("Error: $error") }
)
```

Comment: Thanks your answer David, but I only used that code to reproduce the problem. In project using only
`fun <T> merge(entity: T): Uni<T> {
        return sessionFactory.withTransaction { session -> session.merge(entity) }
}`

Comment: Are you trying to use the same session in parallel? Because it's not gonna work

Comment: I think it would be easier if you could create a test case somewhere.

Comment: For me it's strange: we have method withTransaction for SessionFactory,  which can use existing session, but we cannot use it, because we can't be sure that someone is already using this session. I also tend to you are right. But still I hope there is a right way to use it.
And yet persist works. Without find. And merge uses find...

Comment: It might look like it works in some situations but you should not rely on it. We explain it here: https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_sessions_and_vert_x_contexts